# How to use "Equalizer" with "audio_service" package

Tags: android, flutter, just-audio, audio-service

I am using `just_audio` with `audio_serivce` package. Everything else working fine, now I want to implement an `Equalizer`. I saw the [example](https://github.com/ryanheise/just_audio/blob/master/just_audio/example/lib/example_effects.dart) in `just_audio` regarding adding equalizer. But I'm not really sure how to implement it with `audio_service`.
I have initialized Audio Player like this in the background service:

```
_player = AudioPlayer(
  handleInterruptions: true,
  androidApplyAudioAttributes: true,
  handleAudioSessionActivation: true,
  audioPipeline: AudioPipeline(
    androidAudioEffects: [
      _equalizer,
    ],
  ),
);
```

and using the code in [example](https://github.com/ryanheise/just_audio/blob/master/just_audio/example/lib/example_effects.dart) for flutter UI. But how to use `_equalizer` of Background service in the UI part? I tried accessing it using `customAction` but had no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although controlling the equalizer is not one of the standard media controls understood by smart watches and cars, you can still add this as a custom action: one to set a band's gain, and another to read the the current bands and the min/max decibels supported by the equalizer. You can read about custom actions in the [FAQ](https://github.com/ryanheise/audio_service/wiki/FAQ#how-do-i-send-a-custom-action)

For example, with a custom action, from the UI you might set the gain for a band like this:

```dart
// audio_service 0.17.x
AudioService.customAction('setBandGain', {'band': 0, 'gain': gain});
// audio_service 0.18.x
audioHandler.customAction('setBandGain', {'band': 0, 'gain': gain});
```

And in your background audio task (0.17.x) or audio handler (0.18.x) you can define the callback handler like this:

```dart
// 0.17.x
Future<dynamic> onCustomAction(String name, dynamic arguments) async {
  if (name == 'setBandGain') {
     final bandIdx = arguments['band'] as int;
     final gain = arguments['gain'] as double;
    await _eqParams.bands[bandIdx].setGain(gain);
  }
}
// 0.18.x
Future<dynamic> customAction(String name, [Map<String, dynamic>? extras]) async {
  if (name == 'setBandGain') {
     final bandIdx = extras!['band'] as int;
     final gain = extras!['gain'] as double;
    await _eqParams.bands[bandIdx].setGain(gain);
  }
}
```

Alternatively, if you want a quick and dirty approach, then the following is also possible in 0.18.0 since it runs everything in the same isolate and the whole equalizer parameters object can be passed by reference:

```dart
Future<dynamic> customAction(String name, [Map<String, dynamic>? extras]) async {
  if (name == 'getEqParams') {
    return await _equalizer.parameters;
  }
}
```

Now from your UI you can just obtain the equalizer parameters directly, and then through that object reference you can access its full API (set gain values and also read min/max decibels):

```dart
// in UI
final eqParams = await audioHandler.customAction('getEqParams');
// Now use eqParams as desired.
```

Sure, this breaks encapsulation (but that's why I call this the quick and dirty approach.)

Comment: Ok, I got the point, but how to get the parameters, bands and all, in UI? I tried creating an instance of AudioEqualizer in UI, but it's not giving me any parameters.

Comment: Do I need to get parameters also from the Equalizer Instance in the background service? can't I create another instance in UI?

Comment: It won't work unless you use the same instance that you passed into the player's audio pipeline. If not, that equalizer audio effect will not be attached to the player in any way.

Comment: I have initialized the instance in the background service and then returning Future<AndroidEqualizerParameters>. But the future never returns any value neither in the background service neither in the UI

Comment: The future should complete after an audio source is loaded. If it's not, it may be a bug that you need to report.